# Sand pile - container problem

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling, classical-mechanics

Imagine that there's a box container shown in the graph. (You may consider it as a 2-dimensional rectangle.)

A division plate is in the middle of the container.

A sand pile is on the division plate, falling from the slits between container wall and division plate.

The sand would keep falling until it stops.

The question is what's the shape of the red line shown in the graph? Is there a mathematical solution for the shape?

[image]

Comment: Look up "angle of repose". It's not entirely clear how the diagram should translate to three dimensions, but that constant angle should make the solution pretty easy.

Comment: Just consider the cross section.

Comment: It may depend on the width of the slits, the height-width ratio of the container and the "viscosity" of the sand.

Comment: I guess that it may be straight line, conic section or catenary. Not knowing if one of the guesses is correct.

Comment: The height of the container and width of the slits will have hardly any effect. The difficult part is how the top part will quit flowing over parts of the slits as its pile shrinks, especially with that curved top.

Comment: It is complicated, there are dynamics involved, it is not a statics problem.

Comment: So can someone gives a complete solution if possible?

Comment: Why should this question be closed ? The asker has worked and interacts with us...

Comment: Googling for sandpile model shows quickly that this is a vast mathematics and physics subject in itself. I am afraid that this is not the forum to demand a complete solution.

Comment: @KurtG. If you can find the solution for this particular question, then please give me the link. If not, could you please provide a detailed solution?

Comment: You can be sure that I would to that if I could. You do not seem to get my point and the one given in the comment by @copper.hat. It is not such a simple homework problem as you seem to think. I used to hear about PhDs that worked on such stuff for years.

Comment: @KurtG. I understand your point. But I just want to know the final curve of the red line. Shouldn't it be more like a static problem or so? If it's too complicated, can someone give me a hint or an idea? THANKS

Comment: You underestimate the number of assumptions/parameters that can be involved in such a question. In particular the 2D over-simplification of a real 3D issue... Desiring a "detailed solution" of this complicated issue is a non-realizable dream ; whereas turning your quest into "what would be a reasonable modelization of this situation" can maybe be considered.

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you for telling me. How can I simplify this problem?

Comment: Or just think it as simple as possible first

Comment: For a thin rectangle, or possibly if the slits are along only one dimension and the cross section is constant, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7UM5R-oMBHc from near 2:10 - you get triangles.

Comment: @aschepler thanks for this video. It's very helpful.

Comment: I guess it's true that it'll be straight line if the sand is ideal.

Comment: What would it be like if it's not ideal?

Comment: How to make the red line into other curves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came here from the closed version of this question in the Physics Stack Exchange, but I'd like to provide a solution based on the sandpile model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_sandpile_model). It is possibly too restrictive to be interesting, but I think it is a solution.

Basically, given a 2D grid of the bottom of the container, each grid point can hold some sand. In the sandpile model, the amount of sand held before collapse is equal to the number of neighbors - so here, that's two, except at the boundary - let's say at the boundary, only one grain redistributes to the neighbor. So what shape is that?

It might be easy to see, but it's a straight line. The sand will fill the sides, the extra will tumble to the middle, and when every bin has 1 grain, it saturates. That's not exactly "equilibrium", since one you drop another grain, that grain will bounce around between the bins, but the simulation stops.

I made a silly Google Spreadsheet to show this as well:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TUTONI_Ka33wAxkMOaFXWic5a1qIxotyXsmcplueihY/edit?usp=sharing

It's pretty dumb, since it requires partially updating by hand, but anyway...I think this is a solution for the simplest set of assumptions. A better version would somehow allow for a better gradient between grid points then $1:1$ - like maybe sand can "only move downhill" so that bins like $2$ $2$ $1$ $\to$ $3$ $2$ $1$ $\to$ $4$ $2$ $1$ tumbles to $3$ $2$ $1$ $1$ or something. In that case, I think the answer is the curve would be the absolute value function, centered at the middle.

Comment: Thanks for this solution!